# Form Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am creating a basic form validator but for some reason it never initiates the else statement if anyone could help.

I am sure it is something silly but I am under the impression that on click it will run through the conditionals and if all fails the return false; will return it to the start.

```
$('.get-results').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var get_results = $('.get-results'),
            input_h8_val = $('.input_h8_val'),
            input_h10_val = $('.input_h10_val'),
            input_h12_val = $('.input_h12_val'),
            input_h14_val = $('.input_h14_val'),
            input_h16_val = $('.input_h16_val'),
            input_h20_val = $('.input_h20_val'),
            input_h21_val = $('.input_h21_val'),
            input_h23_val = $('.input_h23_val');

        if (input_h8_val.val() == 0) {
            $(input_h8_val).next('.error').show();
        } else if (input_h10_val.val() == 0) {
            $(input_h10_val).next('.error').show();
        } else if (input_h12_val.val() == 0) {
            $(input_h12_val).next('.error').show();
        } else if (input_h14_val.val() == 0) {
            $(input_h14_val).next('.error').show();
        } else if (input_h16_val.val() == 0) {
            $(input_h16_val).next('.error').show();
        } else if (input_h20_val.val() == 0) {
            $(input_h20_val).next('.error').show();
        } else if (input_h21_val.val() == 0) {
            $(input_h21_val).next('.error').show();
        } else if (input_h23_val.val() == 0) {
            $(input_h23_val).next('.error').show();
        } 
        else {
            console.log("worked");
            $('#first-wrapper').hide();
            $('.predicted').addClass('active');
            $('.predicted').addClass('no-left-radius');
            $('.orders').addClass('no-right-radius');
            $('#second-wrapper').show();
            $('#third-wrapper').hide();
            do_calculations();
        }

    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84cv0b46/1/)

Comment: could you post a JSFiddle with the HTML of your form?

Comment: Did you try to add `console.log()` for your input values to see the exact values being submitted? This way you can debug your code properly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/84cv0b46/

Comment: I have tried console.log and the conditionals seem fine it never reaches the else statement tho.

Comment: Here it works: I change the value of "What percentage of orders are places online?" and click the button and it shows "worked" in the console.
Just remember that, if the user would fill in "0", it wouldn't accept the value.

Comment: With all fields != 0 it worked for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided works for me, but you have to keep a couple of things in mind:

1 - If the user fills in "0" somewhere (as is the case for "What percentage of orders are places online?" by default), the validation will fail.

2 - `next()` only looks for the **immediately following sibling** [link](https://api.jquery.com/next/). So in certain cases, no error will be shown when triggering. (Where there is another `span` behind the input element).

A way to solve this:

```
$(element).parent().find(".error").show();
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. Also the parent selector helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Form Validation Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" intial-scale="1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="G:/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="mailto:Frank@cohowinery.com" 
name="ContactForm" onsubmit="return ValidateContactForm();">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" size="30" name="Name"></p>
    <p>E-mail Address:  <input type="text" size="30" name="Email"></p>
    <p>Telephone: <input type="number" size="30" name="Telephone"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="DoNotCall" 
        onclick="EnableDisable(this);"> Please do not call me.</p>
    <p>What can we help you with?
        <select type="text" value="" name="Subject">
            <option>  </option>
            <option>Customer Service</option>
            <option>Question</option>
            <option>Comment</option>
            <option>Consultation</option>
            <option>Other</option>
        </select></p>
    <p>Comments:  <textarea cols="55" name="Comment">  </textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"></p>
</form>

</body>

<script>
function ValidateContactForm()
{
    var name = document.ContactForm.Name;
    var email = document.ContactForm.Email;
    var phone = document.ContactForm.Telephone;
    var nocall = document.ContactForm.DoNotCall;
    var what = document.ContactForm.Subject;
    var comment = document.ContactForm.Comment;

    if (name.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter your name.");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (email.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0)
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (email.value.indexOf(".", 0) < 0)
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if ((nocall.checked == false) && (phone.value == ""))
    {
        window.alert("Please enter your telephone number.");
        phone.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (what.selectedIndex < 1)
    {
        alert("Please tell us how we can help you.");
        what.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (comment.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please provide a detailed description or comment.");
        comment.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function EnableDisable(chkbx)
{
    if(chkbx.checked == true)
    {
        document.ContactForm.Telephone.disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.ContactForm.Telephone.disabled = false;
    }
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: For the benefit of those reading the question and its answers, could you please elaborate what you did in your code sample that resolves the original problem? Thank you!